# Best E-books and online-resources for Probability and its applications(especially games of chance)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am very much interested in studying games of chance and the probabilities related to our daily life instances but I need an online resource or some e-book to study them. I am a self-learner.

1. Can you tell me some of the best e-books online which has some good in depth matter and its parallel applications(You can also tell me about two different books one for the matter and other for its applications).
2. Is there any prerequisite for this thing (Do I need to study sets and relations in a deeper way or I need just a jist of it).
3. How much matter do you need to completely apply my tools of probability to the daily life.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: (as for 3: not much unless you want to dig your heels in. Some knowledge of classical paradoxes, decision analysis, and the vocabulary of statistics is a healthy start.)

Comment: +1, Why so many downvotes?

Comment: Can i know the reason for the down votes so that i may not repeat the mistake i have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This e-book](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/book.html) is rather interesting: *Introduction to Probability*, by Grinstead & Snell, at Dartmouth. Have also a look at their "Chance" [web site](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/).

If you are intereseted in statistical applications, those may help:

- [NIST *Engineering Statistics* Handbook](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/)
- [Statistics Textbook](http://www.statsoft.com/textbook) from StatSoft

Comment: Thankyou for such an early respone. I will definitely try your recommended book which has a parallel application with concepts.

Answer (score 2):

[Mathematics for Computer Science](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos433/mathcs.pdf) by Eric Lehman and Tom Leighton

This ebook has an excellent chapter on probability, it's not rigorous, but it builds very good intuition.

Comment: thank you for your response, the book is quite good as it includes the basics(to make foundation strong)...I dont think i need to study the all of the chapters in it to know about probability